# Two way binding C++ model in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to learn more about QtQuick and QML. My current goal is to understand how to bind data from a C++ model to my view. So far I've been able to setup the model in my QML and get data from the model but I can't figure out how to update my data.

How do I setup two way binding for my C++ model? Below is the code I've written so far.

**message.h**

```
class Message : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString author READ getAuthor WRITE setAuthor NOTIFY authorChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString message READ getMessage WRITE setMessage NOTIFY messageChanged)

    Q_SIGNALS:
        void authorChanged(QString author);
        void messageChanged(QString message);

    public:
        Message(QObject *parent = 0);

        QString getAuthor();
        void setAuthor(QString author);

        QString getMessage();
        void setMessage(QString message);

    private:
        QString _author;
        QString _message;
};
```

**message.cpp**

```
#include "message.h"

Message::Message(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

QString Message::getAuthor()
{
    return _author;
}

void Message::setAuthor(QString author)
{
    if(author != _author)
    {
        _author = author;
        emit authorChanged(author);
    }
}

QString Message::getMessage()
{
    return _message;
}

void Message::setMessage(QString message)
{
    if(message != _message)
    {
        _message = message;
        emit messageChanged(message);
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import com.butts.messaging 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Test"

    Message {
        id: testMessage
        author: "Batman"
        message: "Hello World!"
    }

    Flow {
        TextField {
            text: testMessage.message
        }

        Label {
            text: testMessage.message
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "message.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qmlRegisterType<Message>("com.butts.messaging", 1, 0, "Message");

    //Message msg = Message();

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

P.S. I'm a giant noob at this so feel free to point out any other issues (formatting, standards, etc.) I have in my code, I need to learn somehow lol

**Edit 1**

After reading @derM's answer I changed my code to achieve what I wanted

```
TextField {
    id: editor

    //Binding model -> view
    text: testMessage.message

    //Binding model <- view
    Binding {
        target: testMessage
        property: "message"
        value: editor.text
    }
}

Label {
    id: display

    //Binding model -> view
    text: testMessage.message
}
```

Comment: There was a talk on this topic on QtWS 2019: https://youtu.be/G6W6MSzM7rs https://www.kdab.com/wp-content/uploads/stories/QmlComponentDesign-TwoWayBindingProblem-AndreSomers.pdf

Comment: [derM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41237532/7621674)'s answer gives an excellent insight into property binding and it pitfalls. However [user240515](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61550652/7621674)'s answer propose a much more concise solution.

Comment: @amura.cxg consider moving your used solution to a separate answer, instead of posting it in your question (as required by the SO policy), otherwise derM's answer seems to be the only correct one.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Twoway binding is a complicated matter in QML, as it usually works as some *assignment*.

So, if you bind a property with `propertyname: valuetobeboundto` and later assign something to `propertyname` again, this binding will be lost.

As a workaround there are two ways: The use of [`Binding`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html)-Objects or to not use binding, but handle all the property-change-signals (which your model ideally properly emits) manually.

For the first, you can find a detailed instruction [here.](http://imaginativethinking.ca/bi-directional-data-binding-qt-quick/)
Here they use the one `Binding`-Object for each direction. The good thing is, those `Binding`s  will not be overridden, by assignment of a new `Binding`.

Consider:

```
Row {
    spacing: 2
    Rectangle {
        id: r0
        width: 50
        height: 30
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: r1
        width: 50
        height: 30
        color: b2.pressed ? 'red' : 'blue'
    }

    Button {
        id: b2
    }

    Button {
        id: b3
        onPressed: r1.color = 'black'
        onReleased: r1.color = 'green'
    }

    Binding {
        target: r0
        property: 'color'
        value: b2.pressed ? 'red' : 'blue'
    }


    Binding {
        target: r0
        property: 'color'
        value: (b3.pressed ? 'black' : 'green')
    }
}
```

At the beginning the value of `r1` is bound to the state of `b2`, but as soon as `b3` has been pressed once, `r1` won't be updated by a click on `b2` anymore. For `r0` the updating will be done by the two `Binding`-Objects, and therefore the `Binding` won't be lost. However, you can see, how the binding works: When ever the state of the `Button` changes, the `Binding` will be updated.
So the press *AND* the release of `b2` will fire signals, that will be handled by the first `Binding` and the same goes for the press *AND* relase of `b3`.

Now coming to the *two-way binding*. Here it is important to avoid Binding-Loops.

```
Row {
    Button {
        id: count0
        property int count: 0
        onClicked: count += 1
        text: count
    }

    Button {
        id: count1
        property int count: 0
        onClicked: count += 1
        text: count
    }

    Binding {
        target: count0
        property: 'count'
        value: count1.count
    }

    Binding {
        target: count1
        property: 'count'
        value: count0.count
    }
}
```

While this example is perfectly fine. The changing of `count0.count` will trigger a change of `count1.count`. Now it is checked, if `count0.count` would need an update, but the value is already the right, so the recursion ends, and no binding-loop occures.

Changing the second Binding to

```
    Binding {
        target: count1
        property: 'count'
        value: count0.count + 1
    }
```

drastically changes the situation: Now with each change of `count0.count`, `count1.count` needs to be raised. The first `Binding` then tries to set `count0.count` to the same value as `count1.count` but there is just no way that both `Binding` will be satisfied, and no change is needed to be done, after the other `Binding` did it's work. It will result in a binding-loop. Luckily those are detected pretty fine in QML, so a lock is avoided.

Now there is only one last thing to take care of:
Consider this Component-Definition:

```
// TestObj.qml
Item {
    width: 150
    height: 40
    property alias color: rect.color
    Row {
        spacing: 10
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 40
            height: 40
            radius: 20
            color: butt.pressed ? 'green' : 'red'
        }
        Button {
            id: butt
            text: 'toggle'
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have an internal binding of the `color`-property, by using the `propertyname: valueToBeBoundTo`-Syntax. This means, the internal binding might be overwritten by any external assignemtn of the `color`-property.
Replace this binding by a `Binding`-Object, and you should be fine.

The same would go the other way around: `color` is externally bound to some value, and then you handle a signal internally and assign a value to it, the external binding would be lost, if not created by a `Binding`-Object.

> This is only a general overview. There are way more details that might alter the behavior of Binding. But I think I have shown, how you can create a *Two-Way-Binding* and mentioned quite some pitfalls, you might encounter.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, with Qt Quick Controls 2:

```
TextField {
    id: txt

    text: testMessage.message

    onTextChanged: testMesage.message = txt.text
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the C++ class notifies when the text is updated, as in "NOTIFY messageChanged" from OP.