# For QML, why LayoutMirroring doesn't work in Slider?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

Today I tried the Slider in QtQuick.Controls, my slider is left to right, I  want to set my slider as from right to left by using **LayoutMirroring.enabled**, at last I found I cann't inverted the slider.

Here is my little demo code, so how can we invert a slider?

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Slider{
        id:test
        value: 0.2
        width:400
        LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `Slider` do you use? From `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` or `QtQuick.Controls 2.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `Slider` from `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` - at least for me - it works like a charm. If you use the `Slider` from `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` it does not.

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layoutmirroring.html):

> Keep in mind, however, that mirroring does not affect any positioning that is defined by the Item x coordinate value, so even with mirroring enabled, it will often be necessary to apply some layout fixes to support the desired layout direction.

The `QtQuick.Controls 1.x`-`Slider` however uses a largely coordinate based [implementation](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Styles/Base/SliderStyle.qml) and has no further precautions to support the `LayoutMirroring`.

However the `Slider`s layout is usually symetrically, so all you need to do is to map the values like from (0,1) to (1,0). This should be a easy task to a developer.

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.3 // Needed for a mysterious value from the original, now mirrored style.
Slider {
    y: 40
    id: sli
    width: parent.width
    minimumValue: 50
    maximumValue: 100

    property real mirroredValue: maximumValue - value + minimumValue

    // Invert style
    style: SliderStyle {
        groove: Item {
            property color fillColor: "#49d"
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            // Whatever TextSingleton is. You need to import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.x for it.
            implicitWidth: Math.round(TextSingleton.implicitHeight * 4.5) 
            implicitHeight: Math.max(6, Math.round(TextSingleton.implicitHeight * 0.3))
            Rectangle {
                radius: height/2
                anchors.fill: parent
                border.width: 1
                border.color: "#888"
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { color: "#bbb" ; position: 0 }
                    GradientStop { color: "#ccc" ; position: 0.6 }
                    GradientStop { color: "#ccc" ; position: 1 }
                }
            }
            Item {
                clip: true
                x: styleData.handlePosition // let the fill-stuff start at the handle position...
                width: parent.width - styleData.handlePosition // and end at the end of the groove.
                height: parent.height
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    border.color: Qt.darker(fillColor, 1.2)
                    radius: height/2
                    gradient: Gradient {
                        GradientStop {color: Qt.lighter(fillColor, 1.3)  ; position: 0}
                        GradientStop {color: fillColor ; position: 1.4}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wan't to set the value of your slider, you need to install a [bidirectional binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232999/two-way-binding-c-model-in-qml/41237532#41237532) between `mirroredValue` and `value`.

Comment: I used QtQuick.Controls 1.3, if so, how could I do this in QtQuick.Controls 1.x?

Comment: I added an example, on how to mirror the value and the style.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. My slider was vertical with values increasing from bottom to the top. I wanted them to increase from top to bottom. I accomplished it using rotation. I think that you could have solved your problem like this:

```
Slider {
    id: test
    value: 0.2
    width: 400
    rotation: 180 // This should make the slider right-to-left
}
```